# How can hide dc.js row chart values if values equal zero

Tags: dc.js

How can we hide if row chart values equal zero in dc.js after filtering .We have a code like this:

```
    var kurum=data.dimension(function(d){return ""+ d.KURUM;});
    var kurumGroup=kurum.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d.INSIDANS});

    kurumRowMapChart
                    .width(300)
                    .height(200)
                    .margins({top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
                    .dimension(kurum)
                    .group(kurumGroup)
                    .colors(d3.scale.category10())
                    .elasticX(true)
                    .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value })
                    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

This code works normally but we want to hiding when  has filter if values equal zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can create a "fake group" which removes the bins containing zeros when `.all()` is called:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

using it like this:

```
var filtered_group = remove_empty_bins(kurumGroup);

kurumRowMapChart.dimension(kurum)
    .group(filtered_group)
    ...
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins

The idea is to create an object which sits between crossfilter and dc.js which looks like a crossfilter group and filters it on demand.

Here is a somewhat complicated example intended to test the transitions between varying numbers of bars:

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/transitions/ordinal-row-transitions.html

(Currently the transitions are not very good but it demonstrates `remove_empty_bins` well.)

Comment: Thanks for answer.But I tried this.It doesnt work.Where can we find any example for this?

Comment: I added instructions for use to the FAQ.  Please try it out and let me know if it works.  I'll see about adding a full example to the dc.js examples.

Comment: An example on the question in your answer would be helpful

Comment: @Chris, thanks, I've made this answer stand on its own and fixed the link.

Comment: Hmm, now I'm getting *down votes* on this? Wow, tough crowd. I've changed variable names to make it clearer how it applies to the original code.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks for the example. How would someone go about restoring the the rows once the filter was removed?

Comment: This should only remove bins whose value is zero, and once they become non-zero they will be restored. This is because `group.all()` is called for every redraw.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon: Great answer! remove_empty_bins() worked for me! :)

I had to use **d.value.count** instead of d.value but I assume this depends on which group-reduce function you are using:

```
return d.value.count !== 0;
```