# DC.js, crossfilter - dynamic chart height when hiding 0-value-bins / groups

Tags: javascript, dynamic, height, dc.js, crossfilter

**I would like to dynamically set the height of a DC-chart, which contains hidden bins.**

It is possible to hide zero-value-bins in a DC-chart with **remove_empty_bins()** function - see following Post:
[How can hide dc.js row chart values if values equal zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305546/how-can-hide-dc-js-row-chart-values-if-values-equal-zero)

I created a group "SubCategoryGroup_nonEmpty", which only contains non-empty bins.
But now my chart-height does not adapt to the count of non-empty bins.

I tried to set the **.height()** with following code:

```
SubcategoryRowChart
    .dimension(SubCategoryDim)
    .group(SubCategoryGroup_nonEmpty)
    .elasticX(true)
    .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.total / p.value.count : 0; })
    ...
    .height(function(anchor) {
        // calculate the height depending on the count of not-hidden bins
        return SubCategoryDim.group().size() * 40; // 40 = size of single element including padding
     });
```

But with **SubCategoryDim.group().size()** i only get the total bins but not the filtered ones:

**How can I get the count of filtered bins?**

Comment: Although you can set the height by passing a function, the function is only called once and the value is cached. You will need also to set the height when the chart is redrawn, which you can do by handling the `preRedraw` event. Easiest way to get the count of filtered bins is `nonEmpty.all().length`

Answer (score 1):

Gordon - You are my savior! Thanks a lot! :)

**Here my final solution:**

- use `nonEmptyGroup.all().length` to get the filtered count of bins
- Create the function `CalcRowChartHeight_bySingleRowHeight()` to calculate row height based on number of bins, row height and margins

```
    function CalcRowChartHeight_bySingleRowHeight(chart, group, SingleRowHeight){
        var ChartHeight = group.all().length * SingleRowHeight;
        var ChartMargins = chart.margins().top + chart.margins().bottom;
        var Height = ChartHeight + ChartMargins
        return Height;
    }
```

- Overwrite the `redraw()` function which sets the `height`. The `_redraw()` function is a copy of `redraw()`. I used it because I did not figure out how to use the `preRedraw` event in this case. Any idea?

```
SubCategoryRowChart
    .dimension(SubCategoryDim)
    .group(SubCategoryGroup_nonEmpty)
    .elasticX(true)
    ...
    .redraw = function (){
        // calculate the height based on the count of non-hidden bins
        SubCategoryRowChart.height(CalcRowChartHeight_bySingleRowHeight(SubCategoryRowChart, SubCategoryGroup_nonEmpty, 40))
        return SubCategoryRowChart._redraw();
    }
    ;
```